# Issues Modelling a complex bottle

Tags: modeling

I'm having an issue modelling the attached bottle. I'm not sure how to bulge the side planes and arc the top. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My apologies for the simplicity of my question. I'm pretty green with blender, and am looking for some recommendations on how to approach modelling the complex planes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd probably get better results modelling these types of geometric technical drawings in a CAD program like FreeCAD and importing into Blender

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75972/how-to-create-little-flanges-on-the-bottom-of-the-bottle/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228436/how-can-i-model-a-bottle-with-triangular-base-and-circular-top-nail-polish-bot/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81596/how-can-i-make-a-rounded-indentation-on-a-cylinder-cosmetic-plastic-bottle-lid https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253199/how-to-create-this-detergent-bottle-recipient/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181914/carve-hole-in-a-metal-water-bottle-model/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206287/how-do-i-make-those-rhombic-indents-in-this-water-bottle-image-in-description https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177662/mesh-plastic-bottle-curved-indent-boolean-or-displacement-map-or-maybe-someth https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75692/creating-curve-design/75697 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134710/how-do-i-make-this-twisted-surface-on-a-bottle/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/making-rounded-dips

Answer (score 2):

Once you've modeled the basic shape...

[image]

pull this face:

[image]

Comment: Would you add a curve to the side plane  to account for the bend? Every time I try, the top arc adds strange geometry.

Comment: Could you please show your current topology? Maybe share it: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sxYVENyq" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sxYVENyq/)

Comment: You don't need so many edges at the top, instead work like I do, with as few edges as possible at the beginning, and quads as much as possible

Comment: Ok, I'll give it another go. You work on one corner and mirror it correct? Sorry for the noob question :P

Comment: Yes I've mirrored on X and Y but actually you should not mirror on Y as it looks like the opposite face is not the same

Comment: Also when you'll give a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object you'll add more edge loops to keep some edge sharp

Comment: @Beamer For the bad shading you show, you probably have inner faces, check inside your object, also select all in Edit mode and press Shift N to recalculate the normals. Maybe also press M to merge by distance

Comment: thanks @moonboots you were extremely helpful. got it looking pretty good!